# Error in Grid search for Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use Grid search optimization technique to improve accuracy for Deep Learning Models in Python With Keras.
Below script i am using

```
# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(train["Group"])
encoder_name_mapping = dict(zip(encoder.classes_, encoder.transform(encoder.classes_)))
print(encoder_name_mapping)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(train["Group"])

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
train_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)

    def create_model():
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=train_data_features.shape[1], activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(len(list(set(train["Group"]))), activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

    # fix random seed for reproducibility
    seed = 7
    numpy.random.seed(seed)

    # create model
    model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model)

    # define the grid search parameters
    batch_size = [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]
    epochs = [10, 50, 100]
    param_grid = dict(batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)
    grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)

    grid_result = grid.fit(train_data_features, train_y)
```

But, I am getting below error. Can anyone please help me in this.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\pool.py", line 362, in get
    return recv()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'create_model' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: Can you include the complete stack trace?

Comment: @VegardKT , As requested I included complete stack trace in query I raised

Comment: are you able to get your create_model function to return a model at all? Can you try to to tmpMdl = create_model()

Comment: @VegardKT, Yes, I tried and seems function return model, I am able to view below results when I used tmpMdl = create_model()                                      >>> tmpMdl
<keras.models.Sequential object at 0x00000285EBB1AA58>

Comment: I tried reroducing your error, but I seem to be able to run your code without error :/ Can you include the rest of your code? Also, check which excact line is throwing the error

Comment: @VegardKT, I included few script in which I am changing target variable which in "group" to onehotcoding and train_data_features contain feature which is used to train model , I am using python 3.5 version and windows 10, I am not sure whether it is issue with multiprocessing

Comment: Yes, Keras, GridSearch and Parallel processing (add to that Windows) dont work well. Can you first try with `n_jobs=1` only?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use the KerasClassifier with GridSearchCV.
I think it´s pretty clear, how you can adapt it.

```
def create_model(optimizer='adam'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSprop', 'Adagrad', 'Adadelta', 'Adam', 'Adamax', 'Nadam']
param_grid = dict(optimizer=optimizer)
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1)
grid_result = grid.fit(X, Y)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing I tried above mentioned but still getting same error. In example  which you share is for binary classification but I am using it for multiclass classification so just change loss='binary_crossentropy' to loss='categorical_crossentropy'

Comment: "Can't get attribute 'create_model'... " has nothing to do with the GridSearch. Furthermore I would suggest to not use epochs and batch_size as hyperparameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GPU for the neural network training, set n_jobs=1 in the GridSearchCV. You probably only have 1 GPU, that argument is for CPU threads.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, could you check the `input_dim=train_data_features.shape[1]` part as I can't see you have defined it anywhere? Try replacing with the shape of your data.